# some questions in a paper by E. H. Neville (1949) about Farey series?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, soft-question, systems-of-equations, farey-sequences

I am reading the paper

MR0029924: Neville, E. H. The structure of Farey series. Proc. London Math. Soc. (2) 51, (1949). 132–144. (Reviewer: W. H. Simons)

and by now two questions raised for me;

1. for the proof of Theorem 1, it says that:

"This theorem is an immediate corollary of the pair of inequalities..."
but it takes almost one page for me to prove it. Is there more simple way that I missed it.

2. It seems Theorem 3 instead of

"...difference $|vx—uy|$ has the value 1 if and only if ..."

must be

"...difference $|vx—uy|$ has the value greater than 1 if and only if ..."

Is there any comments? thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: By using the basic properties of Farey sequences we can show that if $x\in \Bbb R \setminus\ \Bbb Q$ there are infinitely $(a,b)\in \Bbb Z\times \Bbb N$ such that $|x-a/b|<1/(b^2\sqrt 5).$... The value $\sqrt 5$ is the best possible, for if $g$ is the Golden Ratio $(-1+\sqrt 5)/2,$ then using $g^2-g-1=0$ we can how that if $K>\sqrt 5$ there are only finitely many $(a,b)\in \Bbb Z\times \Bbb N$ such that $|g-a/b|<1/(b^2K).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Theorem 1, from $bu-av\ge 1$ and $cv-du\ge 1$ we have $$cbu-cav\ge c$$ and $$acv-adu\ge a.$$ Adding these eliminates $v,$ giving $u=u(bc-ad)\ge c+a.$

Similarly by eliminating $u$ we obtain $v=v(-ad+bc)=d(bu-av)+b(cv-du)\ge d+b.$

Addendum (after acceptance). For Theorem 3, if $|vx-uy|=1$ then by Theorem 1, $no$ rational  between $u/v$ and $x/y$ can have a denominator less than $v+y.$ You are right.

Comment: We have (of course) $u/v>a/b \implies$ $ bv(u/v)>bv(a/b)\implies$ $bu>av\implies$  $bu\ge av+1$. And similarly $c/d>u/v\implies cv\ge du+1.$

Comment: thanks. Do you have any comment the second question?

Comment: Yes. I added to my A.

Comment: thanks again for your answer.